# Как правильно вставить адрес страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

как правильно в `load` вставить адрес страницы из ajax с `url: "pro/wat.php"` и `data:"us=" + us + "&se=" + se`,

```js
if ($('#btn1').attr('class') == 'active') {
  $.ajax({
    url: "pro/wat.php",
    data: "us=" + us + "&se=" + se,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#content").html(html);
    }
  });
}

$('#btn1').load(???);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
data: { 'us' :  us , 'se' : se },
....
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn1").load("pro/wat.php", {
    us: '1', 
    se: '2'
});
```